# How to have individual SetUp functions in Junit

Tags: junit, junit4

I have two test functions and for each I want to have different @Before methods. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you sure that (a) they belong in the same file, and (b) there's a real reason to do the initialization outside the test method?

Comment: I was just curious to know if it can be done

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems to be convenient to organize all the test under the same class, for your case I think the best option is to separate the tests into different classes, each one with his corresponding `setUp`.

An alternative (I prefer the previous option) could be call the `setUp` directly in your test method, like the example as follows:

```
public class FooTest {
   public void setUpMethod1() {
      // do setUp things
   }

   public void setUpMethod2() {
      // do setUp things
   }

   @Test
   public void testMethod1() {
      setUpMethod1();
      // Test
   }

   @Test
   public void testMethod2() {
      setUpMethod2();
      // Test
   }
}
```

Only as a curiosity (IMO not recomended for your case), you can override the default junit `RunListener` with your own implementation. Method `testStarted` is executed before every test and you have access to class and methodName to be able to identify the running test. Dummy sample:

```
public class MyRunListener extends RunListener {    
   @Override
   public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
     //...
      Class testClass = description.getClass();
      String methodName = description.getMethodName();
      //...
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.